# User Defined Aggregate Functions without DLL

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, sql-clr

Is it possible to create a aggregate function without dll? Every aggregate function have to reference a dll? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No. User-Defined Aggregates (UDAs) can only exist as SQLCLR objects. There is no T-SQL equivalent. The same holds true for User-Defined Types (UDTs).

That answer assumes the question is actually asking if UDAs require an Assembly as created via `CREATE ASSEMBLY`.

However, if one interprets the question as asking if a DLL file is required by the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` statement, then no: you can create an Assembly from either a DLL on the file system *or* from a `VARBINARY` literal or variable containing the same bytes that would be in the DLL:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [AssemblyName] FROM 0x1234A6B3......;
```